# Shiny app is failing to load even after applying "app_init_timeout 300;" to shiny config

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have a shiny application hosted on Shiny Server commercial which loads a huge database which is in .Rdata format from global.R and my application is failing to load at the first go as it throws 504 error as below and if we refresh the app, it successfully loads.

[504 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YduHX.png)

I have set "app_init_timeout 300;" in shiny config but the application fails well before that time, infact in less than 60 seconds the app fails with the above error.

Does the app_init_timeout really work in my case or is there any other way that i can get this to work.

Also a lot of the application logs has this on the last line when the app failed to start

/opt/shiny-server/scripts/shiny-run: line 3: 27548 Terminated              /bin/bash --login -c "$SHINY_EXEC_COMMAND $SHINY_R_PATH $*"

Please Help

system('shiny-server --version', intern = TRUE); 
"Shiny Server (Commercial) v1.5.2.764"
"Node.js v6.9.1"

Comment: I suggest you reach out to the shiny team directly as you have the PRO version, they should resolve it in no time

Comment: Obviously I cannot test anything but you could try increasing the value of app_idle_timeout and maybe change some of the other values (see http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#application-timeouts).

Comment: @PorkChop Thanks will get in touch with them for support

Comment: @EliBerkow tried changing the values to -1 also but nothing seems to work, i sometimes get proxy error but then after refreshing the app loads up.
when i check the server stats, everytime when the app starts the CPU is at 100% and if we reload after it errors for the first time, the process continues from where it had errored before

Comment: Very strange. It seems support is your best bet.